# What's the difference between this Mocap and the Mocap+Surface?

Tags: rendering, matcaps

I've been trying to use this free model of a dragon (it's an animation of it flying, by the way) and it's pretty realistic and all but...

[image]

Whenever I try to open it in blender, all I get is this...flat, plastic like results. I feel like that "Matcap+Surface" has something to do with it, but I'm not sure. I'm sorry if the solution to this is simple, but I just can't get it done. Hey, thanks in advance for anything.
[image]

Comment: Firstly, your Blender screenshot shows the _Material Preview_ mode, whereas Sketchfab  says "Final Render". The _Rendered View_ in Blender might look different as well. Secondly, it is quite often or mostly normal that materials are created differently in different softwares, depending on their features and render engines etc. so that you usually don't get the same look when switching between software. And finally, this site is about problems in Blender, if you want to know the differences between Sketchfab's "Matcap" and "Matcap + Surface", you might consult a Sketchfab help site.

Comment: You're totally right! I'll look into it, maybe coming to Stack Exchange for such confusion was a miss haha, yeah, the rendered view still shows the same, it's probably the software...thanks a lot though, I'll contact the owner of this model right away! If not, Sketchfab's help site or something in those words like you mentioned, cheers!